# How to enable screen capture (video) using AppRecordingManager in a WPF project?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, screen-capture

I'm trying to capture a video of my application using UWP APIs, specifically the `Windows.Media.AppRecording` namespace. When I try to execute the code I get a `CanRecord` flag as false, and the reason given by the `Details` property is that "something" is disabled by the user.

How can I enable the screen capture? Do I need a specific configuration file, or manifest?

My application is as simple as it get: Just a WPF in .NET 4.7.2, consisting in a button to start recording and a button to stop recording.

Here is the method:

```
public async Task StartRecordingAsync(string fileName)
        {
            AppRecordingManager manager = AppRecordingManager.GetDefault();
            var status = manager.GetStatus();
            if (status.CanRecord || status.CanRecordTimeSpan)
            {

                var myVideo = await StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(KnownLibraryId.Videos);
                StorageFolder projectFolder = await myVideo.SaveFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

                var audio = await projectFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                var result = await manager.StartRecordingToFileAsync(audio).AsTask<AppRecordingResult>(CTS.Token);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    IsRecording = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsRecording = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

And here are the `Details` given by the `status` variable:

[status.Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icaoK.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IsDisbaledByUser property of the [AppRecordingStatusDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.apprecording.apprecordingstatusdetails?view=winrt-19041) is false when the user does not allow apps to record.

> True if app recording has been disabled by the user; otherwise, false.

To allow apps to record, you need to enable Game Bar from Windows Settings:

Settings -> Gaming -> Record game clips, screenshots, and broadcast using Game bar

Comment: I would never guessed that. This solved my issue. Thank you!